# consultation programming while and if nested

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a little confused, not because I do not work this program.
mails compares a database with a variable.

```
  $correo = "media@gmaeil.com";

$compruebaCorreo=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM email WHERE email='$correo'");


while($imprimeCorreo=mysqli_fetch_array($compruebaCorreo))
{
    if($imprimeCorreo['email']==$correo)
    {
        echo "Ya recibió los tps por su suscripción al Boletín de Todopolicia.com";
    }
    if($imprimeCorreo['email'] != $correo)
    {
        echo "Registramos el correo";
    }
    echo $imprimeCorreo['email'];
}
```

The issue is that if equal, if it meets the first if and echo the while, but if it is not, do nothing, nothing prints, or even the second miss. Where is the fault?

Comment: how could it ever be `!=`? Your query will only return records where email **IS** `$correo`, therefore it is impossible for any of the results to **NOT** be the same `$correo`. you're walking into a store, demanding red apples, and wondering why you didn't get any green ones.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: You can use an `else` in place of `if($imprimeCorreo['email'] != $correo)`. I'm not clear what your current issue is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the email is in your database, you can do it like this.

- `prepare` your select statement

  - by using prepared statements your sql query will always be well formatted, no matter if there are 'weird' charakters in your parameters which might break the sql syntax otherwise
- bind the parameter to the statement and execute it
- store the result of the statement

  - this way we are able to use `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)` in the next step
- use `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)` to check, if the resultset contains at least 1 row

  - if yes: your email is in the database
  - if no: it is not

Code:

```
/**
 * define your select-statement and your parameter(s)
 * let the database prepare the statement and bind the parameters
 */
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT * FROM email WHERE email = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $correo);
$correo = "media@gmaeil.com";

/**
 * execute the statement and storing the result
 */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

/**
 * check the resultset and react accordingly
 */
if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0){
    echo "Ya recibió los tps por su suscripción al Boletín de Todopolicia.com";
}else{
    echo "Registramos el correo";
}
```

Comment: I prefer PDO over mysqli, so there may be better ways to handle the prepared statemens, glad for every hint